# XDebug ignores breakpoints within controller

Tags: php, symfony, xdebug, phpstorm

I'm currently trying to debug an Symfony 2 powered application using XDebug on my local home server. Everything appears to be set up correctly as I'm able to set breakpoints within the app_dev.php file and step through them accordingly.

However any breakpoints set within a bundle's controller get ignored.

The corresponding URL is `http://myapp.local/product-name/`

Does anyone know what could be causing the breakpoint to be skipped?

Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I know that is able to make breakpoints to be "skipped" is a human error mistake... Please postr the code of your Controller and the location of breakpoints. Have you checked that controller action is called with a var_dump ?

Comment: Most likely incorrect/incomplete path mappings (see **Settings | PHP | Servers***). Also -- try **xdebug_break()** function instead of breakpoint in such "unhittable" file -- if path mappings are incorrect PhpStorm will ask to set them up.

Comment: What IDE are you using? I had same problem with netbeans.

Comment: The path for my symfony web directory was set but not the one for the symfony root folder in Settings > PHP > Servers. Changing this solved the problem for me.

Comment: @OzzieOrca, not everyone use PHPStorm :-)

Comment: True. But the question was tagged PHPStorm

Comment: I am having the same issue, could you please explain further what you did to get this to work. I went to PHP > Servers and the only options other than name and host was "Use path mappings" where I could set an absolute path incase a file was a symlink. When I goto debug It stops on the breakpoint, loads some data in the debugger and then instantly "disconnects".

Comment: Shawn Northrop: see my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your folder is symlinked. If yes - you should define proper path in your IDE.

Also as **LazyOne** said **xdebug_break();** works even in symlinked folder;

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know what could be causing the breakpoint to be skipped?

Nothing. The breakpoint is not skipped. The code is just not executed (in debugging mode) at that point.

Take care you have got an active debugging session.

Also if you want more specific help, post the code in question (you probably have set a breakpoint on a line where the debugger does not stop) and the exact steps you do for debugging.